# Process does not show tray icon when it is started by PowerShell on remote machine

Tags: windows, powershell

I have an xxx.exe file on a local machine and I can start a process from this file by powershell. The process can work and show tray icon successfully.

However, when I run this xxx.exe file by powershell on a remote machine which connected to the local machine, I can run the process but it cannot show tray icon.

Here are my powershell commands on remote machine after setting up environment between 2 PC:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$sess = New-PSSession -Credential $cred -ComputerName <local_machine_name>
Enter-PSSession $sess
Start-Process -FilePath "Path/to/xxx.exe" -ArgumentList /silent -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Once run the remote machine can start the process on the local machine. However, there is no tray icon appear.

Is it possible to run a process and show tray icon by a remote machine?

If yes, how can I show it?

Comment: You sure  you want to specify `/silent` argument? Could this be the case?

Comment: What happens when you change `-NoNewWindow` into `-WindowStyle Normal`?

Comment: What program is it?  I don't think graphic programs show up remotely, like notepad.

Comment: my understanding is that remotely started sessions DO NOT run in the current local user session. unless you are running in that session, your code will be kept apart from it. you can use PSExec to do it, but PoSh doesn't seem to have any _direct_ method to do that. it can be done _indirectly_ via task scheduler if you create a task that runs as the "currently logged in user".

Comment: Hi Kirill Pashkov and Theo,


I removed "-ArgumentList /silent" and changed from "-NoNewWindow" to  "-WindowStyle Normal":

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\xxx.exe" -Wait -WindowStyle Normal.

But it still not shows tray icon.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I can do it by PSExec. 
Thank you so much

Comment: @CH4 - you are quite welcome! glad to know you got it working as needed ... [*grin*]